# use of then / catch in $http call in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, asynchronous

I my Node backend have the following end-point:

```
usersRoute.get('/get', function(req, res) {

    //If no date was passed in - just use todays date

    var date    = req.query.date || dateFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
        search  = req.query.search;

    users.getAllUsers(date, search)
        .then(function(results) {
           res.json(results); 
        }, function(err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                success: false, 
                message: 'Server error.',
                data: []
            });
        });
});
```

I have changed my sql table name to something else to trigger the `function(err){}` part

When I use this in my service it looks like this:

```
function getUsers(date, search) {
            return $http.get('/api/users/get', {
                params: {
                    date: UtilsService.formatDate(date),
                    search: search
                }
            })
            .then(getData)
            .catch(handleErr);

            function getData(response) {
                return response.data;
            }

            function handleErr(err) {
                LoggerService.error('Could not retrieve users.', err ,'Ooops');
            }
        }
```

Knowing the server will return an `http status code 500`, I thought it would go right to the `catch block`. But it also returns the data /which is `undefined` in the `then block`

I use my service in my controller like this:

```
function getUsers(date, search) {
            isAdmin();

            vm.loading = true;
            vm.filteredUsers = [];

            return UsersService.getUsers(date, search).then(function(data) {
                vm.loading = false;

                allUsers = data || [];
                vm.filteredUsers = allUsers.slice(0, 50);
                vm.distribution = UsersService.getDistribution(allUsers);

                return vm.filteredUsers;
            });
        }
```

My problem is, since the `then` part is triggered in my `service`. I'm trying to slice `undefined`

My question is: What are som best practices when it comes to this sort of pattern.

Comment: Are you sure your server is responding with a 500? Because that should definitely trigger the catch.

Comment: @FabioAntunes I will edit my question a little bit. The catch is triggered but also the 'then part'.

Comment: Now I get it, I have the solution for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your catching the error from your API and then returning the promise created by `.catch`.

Quick example

```
promise.then(function(data) {
  throw 'Some error';
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err) // will output 'Some error'
}).then(function () {
  // This will run even though we have a catch before
});
```

So how can we prevent the **.then** it's easy we throw an error inside the `.catch`

```
promise.then(function(data) {
  throw 'Some error';
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err) // will output 'Some error'
  throw 'You shall not pass'
}).then(function () {
  // This will not run
});
```

So in your case you have two options, one throw an error as I said or two inject the `$q` service into your service:

```
function getUsers(date, search) {
    return $http.get('/api/users/get', {
        params: {
            date: UtilsService.formatDate(date),
            search: search
        }
    })
    .then(getData)
    .catch(handleErr);

    function getData(response) {
        return response.data;
    }

    function handleErr(err) {
        LoggerService.error('Could not retrieve users.', err ,'Ooops');
        return $q.reject(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! just one question; I used you second option (using $q). it still goes in the 'then' and give me ` Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Comment: @Nilzone- I have created a plunker where you can see everything works fine, https://plnkr.co/edit/v1DOevrEeepDrhDRoFe2?p=preview

Comment: You're absolutely right. I probably missed something. I will have a closer look later today. Thanks for the example! :)

Comment: Still having the same issue. Beacuse in 'then' the response object is undefined. I suspect it has something to do with the way my server sends data back, since a regular http request seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that

```
function getUsers(date, search, cb) {
      return $http.get('/api/users/get', {
           params: {
                date: UtilsService.formatDate(date),
                search: search
           }
      })
      .then(cb)
      .catch(handleErr);

      function handleErr(err) {
           LoggerService.error('Could not retrieve users.', err ,'Ooops');
      }
}
```

And then in your controller

```
 UsersService.getUsers(date, search, function(data) {
        vm.loading = false;

        allUsers = data || [];
        vm.filteredUsers = allUsers.slice(0, 50);
        vm.distribution = UsersService.getDistribution(allUsers);
  });
```

Comment: now it doesn't seem like the catch is called at all.